# getAmountsOut UniswapV2 USDC/USDT pair doesn't return 1

Tags: uniswap

Here is my simple code in Python:

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

abi = [{"name": "getAmountsOut", "type": "function", "inputs": [{"name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256"},
                                                                {"name": "path", "type": "address[]"}],
        "outputs": [{"name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]"}], }, ]



router = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'

exchange_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router, abi=abi)
# dexRouter

# Prices
DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
WETH = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
USDT = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"
USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"

decimals = 6 # Token 0 decimals

result = (exchange_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(Web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), [USDC, USDT]).call())[1];
humanPrice = result/(10**decimals)
rev = 1/humanPrice

print(result)
print(humanPrice)
print(rev)
```

Return is always something around this:

```
5772384686621
5772384.686621
1.732386274112603e-07
```

May be I don't totally understand how getAmountsOut works, but why I can't get 0.99-1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused because the number of decimals for USDC and USDT is different than the number of decimals for ETH. The former two have 6 decimals, the latter 18. The `toWei` function is for ETH.

Change your calling code to this:

```
one_usdc = int(1e6)
result = exchange_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(one_usdc, [USDC, USDT]).call()
```

This should give you a number close to 1000000 (1e6).

If you enter `Web3.toWei(1, 'ether')` as the amount it means you're trying to swap 1 000 000 000 000 (1e12) USDC to USDT. Obviously the exchange rate is terrible because the pool only has a limited amount of USDT in it.

Comment: And for different decimals, like WETH and USDT ?
This works. But I'm trying to understand the logic.

Comment: one_usdc = int(1e18)
result = (exchange_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(one_usdc, [WETH, USDT]).call())[-1];
humanPrice = result/(10**decimals)
rev = 1/humanPrice

Comment: WETH and DAI (for example) have 18 decimals. 1e18 units is a single WETH or DAI.